# Sort listbox items when moving back and forth between select boxes (using ng-options)

Tags: angularjs, sorting, select, listbox

I have created 2 listboxes, one of the left with 4 items (for example ) & other on the right, which is empty. I have 2 buttons in between them, to move stuff from left to right and vice versa.

I have implemented this in angular js.

Now, the problem is that every time I move the element back and forth between the boxes they always get appended to the end, whereas I want them to maintain the sort order (alphabetical) even when the items move between the boxes. For eg. I have 4  colors blue, green,red, yellow on the left. They are in alphabetical order right now. I move red to the left. then when i move to back to right, it gets added at the end of the list i.e. list is now blue, green, yellow,red whereas expected result is blue, green, red, yellow. I am already using 'orderBy' and that sorts the data the very first time it shows up on the UI but moving items back and forth does not retain the sort order.

Is there a way to do this in Angular? Here is my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/0KV9raBlgSuNT3mwKfWp?p=preview

The code in my directive is following :

```
app.directive('dualbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            leftboxtitle: '@',
            rightboxtitle: '@',
            colors: '=ngModel'
        },
        templateUrl: 'dualboxTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $('#add').click(function () {
                var selected = $('#select1 option:selected');
                angular.forEach(selected, function (value, key) {
                    scope.colors.destinationColors.push(value.text);
                });
                return !selected.remove().appendTo('#select2');
            });
            $('#remove').click(function () {
                var selected = $('#select2 option:selected');
                !selected.remove().appendTo('#select1');
                var currentSelect2List = $('#select2 option');
                scope.colors.oldDestinationColors = scope.colors.destinationColors;
                scope.colors.destinationColors = [];
                angular.forEach(currentSelect2List, function (value, key) {
                    scope.colors.destinationColors.push(value.text);
                });

                return
            });
            $("#selectAll").click(function () {
                $('select option').attr("selected", "selected");
            });
        }

    }

});
```

The code in the html template is :

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="144px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="disable" multiple="" id="select1" class="select1 tall" ng-model="selectedColor" ng-options="c.name for c in colors.sourceColors | orderBy:'name'"></select>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">

            <a  href="#" id="add">
              <img src="move_right.png" class="remove" />
            </a>
            <br />
            <a  href="#" id="remove">
              <img src="move_left.png" class="add" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="enable" id="select2" class="select2 tall" multiple="" size="2" ></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <div class="mar20Top mar10Btm flRt"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is my controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('main', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.colors = {sourceColors:[
    {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}

  ], destinationColors:[
    {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}

  ]};

  $scope.dummy=[{name:'rupa', age :"2"},
  {name:'sdfas', age :"2"},
  {name:'ruasdfapa', age :"2"},
  {name:'rusdfaspa', age :"2"}]

   $scope.items = [
    {"id":0,"name":"OG"},
    {"id":1,"name":"OS"},
    {"id":2,"name":"PG"},
    {"id":3,"name":"PS"}
  ];
  $scope.selectedItem=$scope.items[0];

}])
```

Below is the html code where I am using the directive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>

    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
     <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="myController.js"></script>
    <script src="customDirective.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="main">
    <div>
    Listbox Demo: 
                 <dualbox title="ABC Listbox Directive" leftboxtitle="Disabled Profiles" rightboxtitle="Enabled Profiles" ng-model="colors"></dualbox>




                         lasdjflasdjfla
                         asdfjlasjl

                    <select novalidate="" class="select1 tall" ng-options="c.name for c in dummy"></select>
      <select novalidate="" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your insights.. made the changes to my add and remove function and that did the trick. Basically instead of just updating the dualbox... the solution was to update the underlying data. Posting the fix here so anybody with the same problem can use it.

```
 scope.add = function() {
            var selectedObjects = new Array();
            $('#select1 option:selected').each(function(){
                var selectedObject = scope.data.sourceColors[$(this).val()];
                selectedObjects.push(selectedObject);
                scope.data.destinationColors.push(selectedObject);
            });

            for(var i in selectedObjects){
                var idx = scope.data.sourceColors.indexOf(selectedObjects[i]);
                scope.data.sourceColors.splice(idx,1);
            }

        }

        //remove function
        scope.remove = function() {
            var selectedObjects = new Array();
            $('#select2 option:selected').each(function(){
                var selectedObject = scope.data.destinationColors[$(this).val()];
                selectedObjects.push(selectedObject);
                scope.data.sourceColors.push(selectedObject);
            });

            for(var i in selectedObjects){
                var idx = scope.data.destinationColors.indexOf(selectedObjects[i]);
                scope.data.destinationColors.splice(idx,1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to update the underlying data. Posting the fix here so anybody with the same problem can use it.

```
scope.add = function() {
            var selectedObjects = new Array();
            $('#select1 option:selected').each(function(){
                var selectedObject = scope.data.sourceColors[$(this).val()];
                selectedObjects.push(selectedObject);
                scope.data.destinationColors.push(selectedObject);
            });

            for(var i in selectedObjects){
                var idx = scope.data.sourceColors.indexOf(selectedObjects[i]);
                scope.data.sourceColors.splice(idx,1);
            }

        }

        //remove function
        scope.remove = function() {
            var selectedObjects = new Array();
            $('#select2 option:selected').each(function(){
                var selectedObject = scope.data.destinationColors[$(this).val()];
                selectedObjects.push(selectedObject);
                scope.data.sourceColors.push(selectedObject);
            });

            for(var i in selectedObjects){
                var idx = scope.data.destinationColors.indexOf(selectedObjects[i]);
                scope.data.destinationColors.splice(idx,1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your ng-options like this to apply ordering / filtering:

```
ng-options="c as c.name for c in colors.sourceColors | orderBy:'name'"
```

Of course do it on both select elements so that both list display elements in correct order.

And because AngularJS basic behaviour is "My view observe my model data", just remove / add elements to your model and you view should do the rest. At least you should design your directives / app in this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have mentioned in my question that I am already using 'orderBy' and that does not do the trick. Items do not maintain the sort order after you move them between the boxes.

Comment: There was no use of orderBy in your plunker, update it. If you are already using this, i think the problem comes from the way you do your modifications. I can't check it as your link seems to be broken (?)

Comment: I cant figure out if anything is wrong with the plunker or not, but I have pasted the actual code in the question above. Please let me know what the issue is ?

Comment: This kind of instruction is the cause i'm pretty sure: return !selected.remove().appendTo('#select2');  Why ? Because you append item to your list instead of adding this item to your model list, and therefore the sort is not applied. Change this (and other similar instructions) by updating your model list instead. And sorry for the delays when i'm working i always forget to check stackoverflow threads :s